# To insert single quote values into the table using "insert into"

Tags: sql, t-sql

I tried to insert some data from one table (tableA) 
 into another table (tableB) using bulk insert but cannot succeeded because the tableA data has got one value->     `BERMUDA 23''-24''` 
when it tries to enter this value it raise error as

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

My query is

```
insert into tableA 
select size from tableB
```

i try with replace the single quote with empty space but as its size we should enter the data with single quote only.
Please suggest the way out.

Comment: show code of datatable you are creating

Comment: What are the data types of these columns on the two tables?

Comment: VARCHAR(200) .
@AMIT- here no datatable concept am using in sql server.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question: you mentioned `BULK INSERT` twice but it's not used in your code, and you mentioned single quotes but it isn't clear from your question why you know (or think) they're the problem. Can you post some code that shows your problem clearly, e.g. what happens if you execute `insert into tableA (size) select 'BERMUDA 23''''-24'''''`?

Comment: @pondLife i am not passing the single values to the bulk insert query rather am taking the values from another table(tableB) and inserting it into tableA . please see the edit.

Comment: `BULK INSERT` is a [TSQL command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.100).aspx), so please avoid using that term unless you're really referring to it specifically. How do you know that "BERMUDA 23''-24''" is causing the problem, and not some other row in `tableB`? You said that the `size` column in `tableA` is varchar(200), what happens if you `select size from tableB where len(size) > 200`?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove single quote with replace function

```
insert into tableA 
select replace(size,'''','') from tableB
```